# dynamic_cast<B *> (&a) gives a warning

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  virtual void func() {}
};

class B : A
{
  void func() {}
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B* b;

  b = dynamic_cast<B *> (&a);

  if (b == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "Bad cast" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The code behaves as I expect (the cast fails) but I get this compiler warning that I don't understand

> nullptr.cc:18:28: warning: dynamic_cast of ‘A a’ to ‘class B*’ can never succeed [enabled by default]

If I allocate the A object using "new" there is no warning. Why does dynamic_cast not recognize
&a as a pointer?

Comment: It probably does, but I'm guessing theres some static analysis involves that notices that there is no way that a is NOT of type A and therefore the cast will always fail. Such analysis might not be good enough to do the same if you use new.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, I was just concerned there may have been some sort of subtle language thing I was missing.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler *does* recognize `&a` as a pointer to `A`, otherwise it wouldn't compile

But look at your code: `&a` is ALWAYS a pointer to `A`, and never to `B`! It is impossible for an object of type `A` (non-pointer, actual object like you defined `a`) to not be an object of type `A`. It even sounds silly when I write it down.

in your example, `&a` will always, by definition (defining `A a`) be a pointer to `A` and not `B`, so the compiler is letting you know you're doing something silly. BTW - if you compile this with optimization the actual executable won't even attempt the cast, and won't even evaluate your `if` statement. It will probably translate your code to something like:

```
A a;
cout << "Bad cast"<<endl;
```

removing everything it knows in advance the answer to.

Comment: Yes, I realize the code doesn't make much sense. I was just curious about the warning.

Comment: So that's the warning - the compiler is warning you that you're trying something that will always fail. It's a warning, not an error - i.e. it's *legal*, and works but probably not what you were trying to do.

Comment: No, its exactly what I wanted to do. Shine a light into a corner to see if there was anything there.

Comment: Why is there no warning when A gets allocated through "new"?

Answer (score 1):

All the compiler is telling you is that the pointer will never point to an instance of B, and so `b` is always null.

The compiler is recognizing it as a pointer just fine -- it is just trying to help you by flagging questionable behavior. This should be a warning, not an error.

Comment: `nullptr.cc:18:28: warning:`

Answer (score 0):

a is a concrete object and concrete object never points to its sub-class. dynamic_cast works only with pointer and reference.

```
A *ptr;
B *b, b1;

ptr = &b1;

b = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr);

if(b == nullptr){
  cout << "Bad Cast" << endl;
}
```

Please try it.