# Disable "always failing dynamic_cast" warning

Tags: c++, googletest

My situation is similar to [dynamic_cast<B *> (&a) gives a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030262/dynamic-castb-a-gives-a-warning).

I have one base and one derived class:

```cpp
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  int foo() { return 5; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  int bar() { return 10; }
};
```

I have typed unit test which checks that `foo()` returns 5 for both `Base` and `Derived` classes and `bar()` returns 10 for `Derived` class.

```cpp
...
using Types = ::testing::Types(Base, Derived);

TYPED_TEST(Foo, Bar){
  auto obj = std::make_unique<ParamType>();
  auto *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj.get());

  // check logic for Base
  // check logic for Derived if derived != nullptr
}
```

After test instantiation with `ParamType` equals `Base`, the line with `dynamic_cast` produces warning  about dynamic_cast is never succeeds, as it is supposed to be.

How can I disable this warning on gcc compiler?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular warning, but every gcc diagnostic of that nature includes the name of the compiler flag that's responsible for it. The `-Wno-<name>` compiler flag then shuts it off. There's also a pragma that does the same thing, without the need for an option, some digging in gcc's documenation should uncover it.

Comment: When gcc warns about something then it sees clear opportunity to optimize and reason to doubt that you specially wrote so needless and meaningless complications into your code. Are you paid per character written so you want to disable the warning?

Comment: A dynamic cast isn't really necessary as you already know the exact type. E.g. you can just use sy compile time https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: I'd probably have written two separate tests - one testing `foo` on both classes, and the other testing `bar` just on `Derived`.

Comment: You should put derived-specific parts behind `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<ParamType, Derived>)`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I want to test the whole functionality for both Base and Derived classes. I could duplicate Base unit test and populate it with Derived-specific method checks, but this is a code duplication  and I don't really like it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sounds legitimate, but again, code duplication (Base unit test is about 50 lines of code and a lot of the same work needs to be done just to test Derived methods too)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik did not find this warning, my gcc compiler for some reason does not produce warning name

Comment: Then what, exactly, did you mean by "produces warning about dynamic_cast is never succeeds"?

Comment: So you test that dynamic_casting pointer to separate Base object to pointer to Derived always fails? That is testing of compiler not your program.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it fails only with message, no warning short name is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `if constexpr`, something along:

```
TYPED_TEST(Foo, Bar){
  auto obj = std::make_unique<ParamType>();

  // TestBase(*obj);
  if constexpr(std::is_same_v<ParamType, Derived>) {
      // auto *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj.get()); // No longer needed
      // TestDerived(*obj);
  }
}
```